# normalizing before feature extraction for SVM and C 4.5

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-selection, normalization

I'm experimenting with normalization and feature extraction based on Mutual Information before classification for SVM and C4.5. So far I have come to the following conclusions:

- Feature extraction significantly improves C4.5 performance but not SVM performance on real world (finance) data and test data.
- Normalization is needed much more for SVM and practically not needed for C4.5

So as a conclusion C4.5 needs feature extraction and SVM normalization. Are those conclusions correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C 4.5 is a tree based method, they don't need normalization of the predictors. Actually, tree based methods are insensitive to any monotonic transform of the features.

SVMs on the other hand rely on similarity between elements of the train set. If the variables are not scaled, similarity may be driven by one single variable, just because it is expressed on another scale.

So your conclusions about normalization are correct.

As for feature extraction, do you mean feature selection ?

SVMs are known to perform better in high dimensions than most of other ML methods (like C 4.5). Therefore, they usually don't need much of feature selection.

Comment: and what about relation between normalization and feature selection ? Should data be normalized before feature selection based on MI ? Because after normalization for the same FS algorithm different features are selected than on raw data.

Comment: For more consistency, if your prediction algorithm uses scaled variables, the selection step should be performed with scaled predictors as well. However, depending on the law of your variables, the mutual information may be directly related to the correlation between the coefficients, making the scaling optional. Per example, for a gaussian vector (X,Y) : $I(X,Y) = - \frac{1}{2} \log(1 - \rho^2)$ where $\rho$ is the correlation between $X$ and $Y$